# form input field that was automatic generated, doesnt pass to the register form

Tags: php, forms, autocomplete, registration, isset

I have a register form, and I use a script to transform a location to it's latitude and longitude, I'm using lorenzsell / Geocoded-Autocomplete (https://github.com/lorenzsell/Geocoded-Autocomplete/blob/master/README)

It works like a charm, if I fill in the address, then the input fields in my form with the id 
filter_lat and filter_lng are filled with the correct coordinates.

So I was hoping that if I send this to a register form located in register.php,
that it would see these coordinates. But it doesnt.. everything else is defined, only the filter_lat and filter_lng arent. though these are filled in automatically, does this have to do something with it?

```
    <form method="POST" action="register.php">
                                    <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Email: <br/><input type="email" name="email" class="focussed_input" size="15" /><br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Password: <br/><input type="password" name="password" class="focussed_input" size="15" /><br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Name:<br/><input type="text" name="name" class="focussed_input" size="15" /><br />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Age: <br/><input type="text" name="age" class="focussed_input" size="15" /><br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        Address:<br/><input type=text id="mapaddress" class="focussed_input" /><br/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="filter_lat" style="" />                                                                                                                  
                                            <input type="text" id="filter_lng" style="" />
                                            <input type="submit" value="I'm ready!" class="button_inverse" style="padding-left: 23px; padding-right:23px; margin-top:11px;" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                </form>
```

that's the form,
and the register.php code:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['filter_lat'];
echo "include";
include("config.php");
echo "test";
if(isset($_POST["email"])&& isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["age"])){
    echo"na isset";
    $email = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
                if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$email';")) > 0){
                    echo "email already used";

                }
                else{
                    $password = hash('sha512', $salt . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
                    $name = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
                    $age = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']));
                    $lat = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter_lat']));
                    $lng = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter_lng']));
                    $id = '';

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, name, age, lat, lng, type) VALUES ('$id', '$email', '$password', '$name', '$age', '$lat', '$lng', '0');") or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "Account creation successful!";
                }
}


?>
```

anybody used lorenzsell's autofiller before? or someone knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the id of filter_lat and filter_lng to name. It should look something like this -

```
 <input type="text" name="filter_lat" style="" />                                                                                                                  
 <input type="text" name="filter_lng" style="" />
```

You are retrieving data with $_POST at server side, but you can't retrieve data without name. So basically, you were trying to retrieve data filter_lat which doesn't exist.

Attribute id is mostly ment for CSS and javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The problem is they don't have the "name" attribute defined:

```
<input type="text" id="filter_lat" style="" />                                                                                                                  
<input type="text" id="filter_lng" style="" />
```

change to:

```
<input type="text" id="filter_lat" style=""  name="filter_lat"/>                                                                                                                  
 <input type="text" id="filter_lng" style="" name="filter_lng"/>
```